# Java 6 regex multiple matches of one group

Tags: java, regex

Here is simple pattern: `[key]: [value1] [value2] [value3] [valueN]`

I want to get:

1. key
2. array of values

Here is my regex: `^([^:]+):(:? ([^ ]+))++$`

Here is my text: `foo: a b c d`

`Matcher` gives me 2 groups: `foo` (as key) and `d` (as values).

If I use `+?` instead of `++` I get `a`, not `d`.

So java returns me first (or last) occurrence of group.

I can't use `find()` here becase there is only **one** match.

What can I do except splitting regex into 2 parts and using find for the array of values?
I have worked with regular expressions in many other environments and almost all of them have ability to fetch "first occurrence of group 1", "second occurrence of group 1" and so on.

How can I do with with `java.util.regex` in JDK6 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify the point about there being "only *one* match?" There's no way to capture an indeterminate number of matches like you're asking, so some iteration is required here.

Comment: It is already 2013 and there is still no decent solution to this problem! *facepalm*

Answer (score 9):

The total number of match groups does not depend on the target string (`"foo: a b c d"`, in your case), but on the pattern. Your pattern will always have 3 groups:

```
^([^:]+):(:? ([^ ]+))++$
 ^       ^   ^
 |       |   |
 1       2   3
```

The 1<sup>st</sup> group will hold your key, and the 2<sup>nd</sup> group, which matches the same as group 3 but then includes a white space, will always hold just 1 of your values. This is either the first values (in case of the ungreedy `+?`) or the last value (in case of greedy matching).

What you could do is just match:

```
^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$
```

so that you have the following matches:

```
- group(1) = "foo"
- group(2) = "a b c d"
```

and then split the 2<sup>nd</sup> group on it's white spaces to get all values:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^([^:]+):\\s*(.*)$").matcher("foo: a b c d");
    if(m.find()) {
      String key = m.group(1);
      String[] values = m.group(2).split("\\s+");
      System.out.printf("key=%s, values=%s", key, Arrays.toString(values));
    }
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
key=foo, values=[a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: One, I think she meant `(?:` not `(:?`.  But more importantly, this does get asked for a fair bit. I believe C# has a way of doing this. It might be useful to extend the API so that one could retrieve an array of matches for the Nᵗʰ group via `group_array(N)` or some such; you would need a new pattern compile flag to enable that, since it’s too expensive for general use. In Perl would could use arrays `@1` and `@2` instead of scalars `$1` and `$2`, and  even define `$1` to mean `$1[$#1]` etc. Is that useful, wicked, or both? :)

Comment: @tchrist, yeah, you could be right about the `:?` <-> `?:`. I'm not very familiar C#, and never heard of this N-grouping feature (do you have a link to the MSDN docs for me?). And it would definitely be both useful and wicked! :)

Comment: what make me pollute myself? :) [This suggests it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966(v=vs.71).aspx#Y2320) under Capture Collection and under Capture.  I have trouble reading that, though. :)

Comment: Is there any other engine that allows to capture all the repeated group matches? Because it will be an overkill if I'll do regex matching over regex results

Comment: @Uko, I don't know. Feel free to create a new question, of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(":?\\s+"));
String key = s.next();
ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
while (s.hasNext()) {
    values.add(s.next());
}
System.out.printf("key=%s, values=%s", key, values);
```

It prints:

```
key=foo, values=[a, b, c, d]
```