# Scala Regex to parse URL

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have written this code in scala

```
val regex = "^(\\w+):\\/{2}(\\w*)\\.?([^\\/]*)([^\\?]*)\\??(.*)?".r
val x = "http://www.google.com/foo/bar/baz.html?x=10&y=20&z=20"
regex.findAllIn(x).matchData.foreach{x=> println(s"${x.group(1)} ${x.group(2)} ${x.group(3)} ${x.group(4)} ${x.group(5)}")
```

This works very well and I get the desired output of

```
http 
www 
google.com 
/foo/bar/baz.html 
x=10
```

However I need a way by which I can loop over the last part and generate strings for all parameters like

```
x=10
y=20
z=30
```

I am not clear as to how to extract the last part in a recurring way.

I know there are lots of existing regex to parse URLs on the internet ... but I am trying to understand regex and write my own. (just to learn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a fixed number of parameters, you can just repeat the last group as many times as necessary. For example, if there are always 3 parameters, you would use

```
"^(\\w+):\\/{2}(\\w+)\\.([^\\/]+)([^\\?]+)\\?([^&]+)&([^&]+)&([^&]+)".r
```

Otherwise, if the number of parameters varies, there is no regex-only solution for this problem, as it is not possible to extract multiple matches with a single match group. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7215157/1374678) for more information.

To work around this problem, you can use the following regex

```
"^(\\w+):\\/{2}(\\w+)\\.([^\\/]+)([^\\?]+)\\?(.*)".r
```

in which the last group matches all parameters and then split the last match using something like

```
lastMatch.split("&")
```